# Consume a webservice - WS Security

Tags: c#, web-services, wss, apache-axis, x509certificate

I am about to develop a windows applikation which need to communicate with an Axis2 webservice using Web Service Security - all the documentation says is, that the SOAP security communication is configured to TIMESTAMP, SIGNATURE, ENCRYPT and the the certificate of my company must be installed in my keystore and the SOAP client I am about to develop must trust the webservice-provider certificate. But from here I am lost.

I know how to use a regular webservice - but with the above informations nothing I know of or do will succeed, all I have figured out so far is installing Web Service Enhancement 3.0. Im using VS2008/C#.

Does anyone knows a good guide or provide a code-sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to the WSE 3.0 Quick Start Examples:

[WSE QuickStarts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa528840.aspx)

If you're using VS2008 though, you should considering building your client using WCF. You won't need to install WSE 3.0 as the security standards are built-in. Here's a WCF reference that should get you started on the security aspect:

[Common Security Scenarios (WCF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx)

Comment: I have now been testing a bit with WCF - but how can I make sure that I fulfill the requirements from the documentation? I keep getting errors, either a 400 error or an error saying that my request was rejected by the soap-service - is it because I call the soap-service as a regular webservice and therefore not fulfill the WSS-requirement or what am I missing?